# How to update existing excel work sheets?

Tags: python, excel

I have an existing excel workbook with 6 sheets in it named Z_df_pca, Z_df_kpca, Z_df_ae, Y_pred_pca, Y_pred_kpca and Y_pred_ae. Imagine these sheets to be full of data obtained from my some simulation.

I want python to revise or update one of these sheets with following conditions:

1. Other sheets should not be affected.
2. Should not create copies of sheets or the workbook. Example: instead of updating Z_df_pca, creates Z_df_pca-1 and so on.

Whats the simplest way I can write to these 6 sheets given that I have a dataframe as an output to be written?

Comment: first write code and come back when you get error message.

Comment: if you're using pandas then `df.to_excel` look at `engine` arguments and `append`

Comment: If you want .xlsx type of files, then you need to use some specialized module that can dive into the bundles of xml files that make up native microsoft excel files; something like openpyxl (I google'd it). Your other alternative is to save Comma Separated Value files, or CSV files. CSV files have nothing to do with excel, but excel does open them and show you the data inside. Hence, writing a CSV file in python is a common way to produce an excel-type file that can be used in excel later.